# Predict_proba for IsolationForest

Tags: python, scikit-learn

[I try to use an isolation Forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) for an outlier detection (fraud detection). If I run the code below (with train and test set):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
iso = IsolationForest(random_state=0).fit(X_train)
isopred = iso.predict(X_test)
```

I get an array with: `array([1, 1, -1, ..., 1, 1, 1])`
which contains 1 or -1. How can I use `predict_proba` which I can use for [DecisionTrees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html). Is there a function available for IsolationTree in the docs it is not mentioned?

When I run: `iso.predict_proba(X_test)` I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'IsolationForest' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

I am searching for an array, which gives me the probability which class (outlier or not) the predction belongs to.

My `X_test` looks like:

```
A  B  C
11 1  0
11 3  0
11 0  1
```

and `y_test.values.ravel()`:
`array([0,0,1])`

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I added it, but this will help, in the docs is also sample data...

Comment: I just wanted to get a feel for your data to see if it had any particularity. I'll edit my answer to use these examples, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a *predict_proba* in this module, because it does not use probabilities to evaluate each sample as an outlier, but instead a score.

Looking at the documentation you provided, each samples is classified using a decision function with the following formula:

```
decision_function = score_samples - offset_. offset_
```

So what you probably want is *score_samples*. Using sample data:

```
X = [[-1.1], [0.3], [0.5], [100]]
iso = IsolationForest(random_state=0).fit(X)
iso_pred = iso.predict([[0.1], [0], [90]])
iso_scores = abs(iso.score_samples([[0.1], [0], [90]]))
```

Results in:

```
[ 1  1 -1] 
[0.33644293 0.35190077 0.62865009]
```

After subtracting the offset (by default=-0.5) to each sample, if the returning result is positive, its an inlier, otherwise its an outlier.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: `score_samples`is a nice function, however i think i need to add `abs`to it, cause all my values are negativ

Comment: The only questio is, that the values are now in a range from 0.3 - 0.7, normally in decision trees I get values between 0-1. Is this a behavior of isolation forest?

Comment: I wouldn't use _abs_ as according to the documentation the lower the value the more abnormal it is and you might encouter positive values in the future that will be mixed in with other outliers/inliers.

Comment: The scores you get now aren't the final classification but instead a middle step to such classification. 0 or 1 values have no special meaning in this approach, afaik..